# Which role will the Windows firewall check against the tunneled data?

Tags: windows, ssh-tunnel

By running an SSH tunnel to a windows remote server connection as described in the following links-

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/6194/windows-xp-vista-win7-setup-a-secure-remote-desktop-tunnel-connection-with-ssh-copssh-and-putty/

http://klinkner.net/~srk/techTips/ssh-remote/

By typing `localhost:3390` in my remote connection program at the client side, and assuming I have the tunnle- from `local 3390` to server `1.1.1.1:3389` (1.1.1.1 is the server) and I run the sshd process (with the tunnel) on port 22 at the server (and also port 22 at the client ssh), What rules will be checked by the server's firewall?

rule of port 22 for the packet that arrive to the sshd process? port 3389 for the data arrive to the server's remote connection process? both?

In case the firewall will check the data against the rule of port 22, I could disable the roles allowing incoming data to the server's port 3389, i.e not allowing regular remote desktop connection thus allowing only SSH tunneled connections, which is my whole intention.

Comment: Did you mean an **SSH** tunnel?

Comment: to clarify, are you trying to forward server port 3389 to your (ssh client) machine on port 3390?

Comment: Client port 3390 -> Tunnle -> Server [sshd port 22 \\ remote-desktop-app port 3389]. The sshd process in the server will forward data to it's port 3389 as defined by the tunnel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this isn't exactly a "tunnel". The SSH manual calls it a "port forward", which is a mode accurate description, since it handles a single TCP port.

Secondly, there are two types of forwarding: forward (`-L`) and reverse (`-R`). From the articles you linked to, you're referring to the former.

On a forward port forwarding like `-L 3390:localhost:3389` there will be exatly **one new *open* port** (besides the usual SSH port listening on the server - usually 22) - that's **port 3390 on the client side**

The connections that are happening, and that your firewall(s) need to allow are:

- The SSH client connects to the SSH server on (default) port 22
- The SSH server connects to port 3389 on the server itself

SSH doesn't (can't) care about port 3389 on the server. It's up to another process to open it.

This is made clearer if you note that `localhost` part is *from the viewpoint of the server*, and that you can specify any other host that the server can reach.

Comment: @user2162550 Yes, possibly. I didn't answer your only explicit question ("What rules will be checked by the server's firewall") because I think that question is not answerable - the only person that can answer that is whomever implemented (microsoft? cisco? linux kernel developers?), deployed and configured (you? your server admin?) that firewall. Instead, I told you which ports you need your firewall to allow through (further assuming you're allowing all outgoing connections). Is there something else you need to know?

Comment: I didn't understand you concept, could you try to give an explanation with reference to my specific scenario ?

Comment: @user2162550 I've edited the answer to fit your scenario more closely and explicitly list the connections that are happening (that you need your firewall to allow). I'm not sure I can help you further without additional details. If you feel confused by any concepts I mentioned (open ports, port forwarding, listening), I recommend you read up on IP networking in general, and [sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) in particular

Comment: by saying "The SSH server connects to port 3389 on the server itself", do you mean that if I'll block incoming data from port 3389 at my server's firewall, the process won't work?

Comment: @user2162550 The connection is coming from the server itself. While I have no experience with Windows Firewall, I think most firewalls won't filter loopback connections unless told to explicitly. If you need help with the firewall configuration in particular, superuser is probably the best place to ask